# Realm-js: Cannot access realm that has been closed

Tags: node.js, react-native, realm

Realm keeps throwing this error in a simple use case: 
`Cannot access realm that has been closed`

My files: 
RealmExample.js

```
import Realm from 'realm';

class Item {}
Item.schema = {
  name: 'Item',
  properties: {
    name:  'string',
    date: 'date',
    id: 'string'
  },
};
export default new Realm({schema: [Item]});
```

app.js

```
//My imports
export default class App extends Component<{}> {
  render() {
    return (
      <RealmProvider realm={realm}>
        <ConnectedExample />
      </RealmProvider>
    );
  }
}
```

ConnectedExample.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  Text,
  ScrollView,
  TouchableOpacity,
  View,
  StyleSheet,
} from 'react-native';
import uuid from 'uuid';
import { connectRealm } from 'react-native-realm';
import ConnectedExampleItem from './ConnectedExampleItem';

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  screen: {
    paddingTop: 20,
    paddingHorizontal: 10,
    backgroundColor: '#2a2a2a',
    flex: 1,
  },
  add: {
    height: 44,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    paddingHorizontal: 10,
    backgroundColor: '#1a1a1a',
  },
  addText: {
    color: 'white',
  },
});

class ConnectedExample extends Component {

  count = 0;

  onPressAddItem = () => {
    const { realm } = this.props;
    realm.write(() => {
      realm.create('Item', {
        name: this.count.toString(),
        date: new Date(),
        id: uuid.v4(),
      });
      this.count++;
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.screen}>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.onPressAddItem} style={styles.add}>
          <Text style={styles.addText}>Add Item</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <ScrollView>
          {this.props.items.map((item) => (
            <View key={item.id}>
              <ConnectedExampleItem id={item.id} />
            </View>
          ))}
        </ScrollView>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

export default connectRealm(ConnectedExample, {
  schemas: ['Item'],
  mapToProps(results, realm) {
    return {
      realm,
      items: results.items.sorted('date') || [],
    };
  },
});
```

ConnectedExampleItem.js

```
import React, {
  Component,
  PropTypes,
} from 'react';
import {
  StyleSheet,
  TouchableOpacity,
  Text,
} from 'react-native';
import { connectRealm } from 'react-native-realm';

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  item: {
    height: 44,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    paddingHorizontal: 10,
    marginTop: 10,
    backgroundColor: 'cyan',
  },
});

class ConnectedExampleItem extends Component {

  onPressRemoveItem = (item) => {
    const { realm } = this.props;
    realm.write(() => {
      realm.delete(item);
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <TouchableOpacity
        onPress={() => this.onPressRemoveItem(this.props.item)}
        style={styles.item}
      >
        <Text>{this.props.item.name}</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    );
  }

}

export default connectRealm(ConnectedExampleItem, {
  schemas: ['Item'],
  mapToProps(results, realm, ownProps) {
    return {
      realm,
      item: results.items.find(item => item.id === ownProps.id),
    };
  },
});
```

The strange thing is that when running this code on my project I run into the `Cannot access realm that has been closed` (I haven't instantiated Realm anywhere else), however, if I run the example in the `react-native-realm` repo, it runs fine.

Also, the introduction example on the Realm documentation page runs fine as well.
What could be the issue?
Thank you.
PS: Running on React-native 0.51, Android device 6.0.

Comment: @famfamfam Not exactly. Please see https://github.com/realm/realm-js/issues/1589 for a workaround.